# Word play. Guess the word

Tags: word, wordplay

> I normally move effortlessly along my path like you on tar.
>   Without my first letter I can only walk straight.
>   A part of me is frequently used to refer celestial bodies.
>   Sans my second letter I am something that is priceless yet cheap.

Guess the word.

Comment: Is the first sentence supposed to be sarcastic? Tar is quite sticky, making moving upon it not effortless.

Comment: Nope. I mean tar roads.

Comment: Yes I mean that. They are commonly called tar roads here. You can ignore tar. It moves effortlessly like how you would walk on a footpath.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are a:

> Brook

I normally move effortlessly along my path like you on tar:

> You flow like a river

Without my first letter I can only walk straight:

> You become 'rook,' a chess piece that can only move in straight lines

A part of me is frequently used to refer celestial bodies:

> **B**, **O**, and **K** are all spectral classifications of stars

Sans my second letter I am something that is priceless yet cheap:

> You become a 'book,' a cheap but extremely valuable item

Comment: I like this answer. I would be surprised if it isn't right.

Comment: May I ask how you come up with these answers?

Comment: Orb (reverse bro) is also used to refer to celestial bodies. How did you guess the word? Even I'd like to know so that I can ask harder questions next time.

Comment: Heh, I thought the stellar classification this was a bit odd.  As for how I solved it:  first, I started brute forcing names for describing celestial bodies.  Star, comet above, up, twinkle.  Nothing but dead ends.  Then I moved on to the first clue.  I started writing down modes of transportation and playing with the letters.  This was failing until I reread the clue. "effortlessly along MY path" implied the direction was predetermined, and the second clue implied that the path was NOT straight.  That got me onto roller-coaster, then to river, then to brook.

Comment: Definitely makes sense...

Answer (score 3):

Is it...

> Heaven?

I'm curious if

> Eaven is an alternate spelling of even.

Priceless but cheap certainly describes

> Havens.

Celestial bodies are very commonly called

> The heavens.

Comment: Seriously an awesome answer. It only meets the last two criteria though :)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking there might be a car model by that name that I didn't know about.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be

> Trail?

I normally move effortlessly along my path like you on tar.

> Explains itself

Without my first letter I can only walk straight.

> Rail

A part of me is frequently used to refer celestial bodies.

> not sure about this one

Sans my second letter I am something that is priceless yet cheap.

> Tail

Comment: The last one made me laugh. Not the answer but I've learnt that next time I should think of difficult riddles. I'm surprised by the number of possible words that almost meet a riddle :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking:

> Plane?

it moves effortlessly:

> A Plane doesn't tend to have any obstacles in the sky

Without its first letter:

> Lane which tend to stay straight although you can certainly have curvy lanes

Part of me is used for celestal bodies:

> PLANEt

And without second letter:

> Pane which I don't know if anyone considers panes priceless

Comment: Nice loophole (the celestial body part). I forgot to mention that the letters are within me.